# Can I wallpaper over spackle?

Tags: wallpaper

I have a small areas that I want to do wallpaper on. However there are a few spots on this wall that needed patchwork and are spackled. My question is, can I wall paper right over the spackle or does it need some kind of primer on it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are some types of spackle out there that claim they do not need primer over it, you may be safe with that, it is always recommended to primer under wall paper, it aids in the removal process later. If you have no paint on hand at all, get primer, if you have any latex paint around at all, that will suffice for a spot on the wall here and there.